# why this variable stay true?

Tags: php, validation

I try to create a field validator by PHP. I want to change an index global variable to check it later for execute my query, and also i want to change my elements directly. BUT my index variable not chang when happend a error! Check Me Please!

```html
<?php

$isValid=1;

function validation($indexForm,$inputName,$require,$type,$tblName=NULL,$fldName=NULL){
 
 global $isValid;
 if(isset($_POST[$indexForm])){
  
 if($require==1||$require==true){
 if(!isset($_POST[$inputName]) || $_POST[$inputName]==''){
   $isValid=0;
   echo " style='border:solid red 1px;' title='Fill Required' ";
   }
  }
  
 if($type=='int' && isset($_POST[$inputName]) && $_POST[$inputName]!='' && filter_var($_POST[$inputName],FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)===false ){
   $isValid=0;
   echo "style='border:solid red 1px;' title='Integer Required'";
   }
 if( $tblName && $fldName ){
   if(mysqli_num_rows(query("select * from `".$tblName."` where ".$fldName."='".$_POST[$inputName]."';"))!=0){
    $isValid=0;
    echo " style='border:solid red 1px;' title='Unique Required'";
   }
   }
}
return;
}

?>
```

Comment: question: *why* are you using a global variable, instead of letting your function *return* the desired value?

Comment: Hi dear :) i want to handle my elements directly by change 'border and title' without get it's value. and finaly just by check $isValid I'll try to handle my form action

Comment: yeah, i can see that, but the question was: *why in the world* would you need, want, or even consider using a global variable for that?